# Android: Parse JSON Array PHP

Tags: php, android, json

Please help, I'm having a hard time parsing the `o_total` array, parsing `orders` in a ListView and is successful but when I'm trying to parse `o_total` in a textview it keeps throwing me No Value for `o_total`

This is the JSON:

```
 {"orders":[{"id":"5","ord_name":"Cafe Americano","ord_desc":"Hot Cafe Americano","ord_price":"60","ord_qty":"2","customer_id":"54fb83cb15e66","ord_num":"13211554fb83cb15e66","price_x_quan":"120.00","image":"http://192.168.43.52/MMOS/uploads/cafeamericano.jpg","subtotal":"","imgimg":"uploads/cafeamericano.jpg"},{"id":"8","ord_name":"Nestea Bottle","ord_desc":"Nestea in a bottle","ord_price":"15","ord_qty":"2","customer_id":"54fb83cb15e66","ord_num":"13211554fb83cb15e66","price_x_quan":"30.00","image":"http://192.168.43.52/MMOS/uploads/nestea_bottled.jpg","subtotal":"","imgimg":"uploads/nestea_bottled.jpg"},{"id":"9","ord_name":"Cafe Americano","ord_desc":"Hot Cafe Americano","ord_price":"60","ord_qty":"1","customer_id":"54fb83cb15e66","ord_num":"13211554fb83cb15e66","price_x_quan":"60.00","image":"http://192.168.43.52/MMOS/uploads/cafeamericano.jpg","subtotal":"","imgimg":"uploads/cafeamericano.jpg"}]}{"o_total":[{"total":"210"}]}
```

This is my PHP Code:

```
    <?php
``mysql_connect('localhost','root','')or die ('No Connection');
mysql_select_db('dbmoms');

$sum=0;
$total = $sum;


$sql1 ="SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY id desc  LIMIT 1"; 
if($row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql1))){
    $order_id=$row['ord_num'];
}
$sql ="SELECT * FROM orders  WHERE ord_num = '$order_id' "; 


$result = mysql_query($sql);
$arr["orders"] = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $arr['orders'][]= $row ;
    $sum = $sum+$row['price_x_quan'];



}
    $arr1= array();
    $arr1['o_total'][] = array('total' => "$sum" );


$json_encoded_string = json_encode($arr); 
$json_encoded_string1 = json_encode($arr1); 

 $json_encoded_string = str_replace("\\/", '/', $json_encoded_string);


echo $json_encoded_string;
echo $json_encoded_string1;


?>
```

I want to show o_total in my Android:TextView please help.

```
@Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParserConfirmation jParser = new JSONParserConfirmation();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
             pDialog.dismiss();


             try {
                    // Getting JSON Array
                    user = json.getJSONArray("o_total");
                    JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);


                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    String id = c.getString("total");


                    //Set JSON Data in TextView
                    i_pay.setText(id);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


         }
```

Comment: Please show your Android code that you are trying to use that isn't working.

Comment: Why would you manually modify a json string generated by `json_encode()`? And another problem is that you output 2 json strings after each other, so the result will not be valid json. Passing your json through jsonlint.com will show you that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is invalid. You can't have multiple roots in your json data.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$arr["orders"] = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $arr['orders'][]= $row ;
    $sum = $sum+$row['price_x_quan'];
}
$arr['o_total'][] = array('total' => "$sum" );

$json_encoded_string = json_encode($arr);  

// not sure this is necessary
$json_encoded_string = str_replace("\\/", '/', $json_encoded_string);

echo $json_encoded_string;
```

Comment: any idea how to make my json Valid? i wanna calculate the price_x_quan in my JSON and put it in  o_total

Comment: Omygosh !!! Its Perfectly Working !! You saved my THESIS !! wooo! Cheers !!! ^_____________^ Thank you very Much